# Using the ResetPassword notification email template for custom emails

Tags: php, laravel

I generated a new email object through the artisan command to notify users about cumulative notifications. I succeeded using a custom template through the build method of the Email object:

```
public function build()
{
    return $this->view('email.cumulative-notifications')
        ->with(['amount' => $this->amount])
        ->subject('You have some notifications!');
}
```

I want to use the template that is used for the reset password email which can be filled with lines and links like the ResetPassword does:

```
public function toMail($notifiable)
{
    return (new MailMessage)
        ->subject('Reset Password')
        ->greeting('Hello!')
        ->line('...')
        ->action('Reset Password', url('password/reset', $this->token))
        ->line('...');
}
```

Should I use Notifications objects instead of Emails?